# right text align mat-expansion-panel material component

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I want to align the description text of `mat-expansion-panel` component to the right

I have tried using align-text to right but nothing is changing
Here's my HTML

```
<mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        Cycle ingénieur en informatique
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        2014-2017
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    ....
  </mat-expansion-panel>
```

CSS :

```
mat-panel-description {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Here's the actual behavior

[image: example]

I would have that 2014-2017 stay stuck to the right.

Comment: Can you check that the parent element is 100% of the width of the container?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The panel header content are contained in a span which is a flexbox so you can use that to push the contents out to the sides.

view:

```
<mat-expansion-panel>
<mat-expansion-panel-header class="right-aligned-header">
  <mat-panel-title>
    Cycle ingénieur en informatique
  </mat-panel-title>
  <mat-panel-description>
    2014-2017
  </mat-panel-description>
</mat-expansion-panel-header>
```

css (this has to be global css eg. styles.css not in the component style):

```
.right-aligned-header > .mat-content {
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.mat-content > mat-panel-title, .mat-content > mat-panel-description {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

Here is a [Stack Blitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kano2a)

Comment: Can you explain why this has to be in gobal styles.css ?

Comment: i would expect it has something to do with shadow dom in the component and the global styles (default styles) will overwrite them ...

Answer (score 12):

Based on this solution: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10024

```
.mat-expansion-panel-header-description, .mat-expansion-panel-header-title {
  flex-basis: 0;
}
```

and reading again the problem, this worked for me:

```
.mat-expansion-panel-header-description {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: Actually, [your solution](https://angular-kano2a-ghtkab.stackblitz.io/) is not the desired behavior, the op wants. [Here's the accepted answer's solution](https://angular-kano2a.stackblitz.io/) Which is what the OP wants

Answer (score 6):

The easiest solution I found is to reset `flex-grow` of `mat-panel-description`:

```css
// my.component.css

mat-panel-description.right-aligned {
  flex-grow: 0;
}
```

```html
// my.component.html

...
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-description class="right-aligned">
      2014-2017
    </mat-panel-description>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
...
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kano2a-mujabw?file=app/expansion-overview-example.css)

Comment: it did work for `.mat-expansion-panel-header-description.right-aligned` class

Answer (score 0):

Add fxLayoutAlign="end" to mat-panel-description. It worked for me.

```
'<mat-panel-description fxLayoutAlign="end">
2014-2017
</mat-panel-description>'
```